# Eclipse and OpenCV on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, linux, opencv, include

I have installed Eclipse+CDT and OpenCV with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcv1 libcv-dev libcvaux1 libcvaux-dev \
libhighgui1 libhighgui-dev \
opencv-doc \
python-opencv
```

After that I've opened Eclipse and created a new c/c++ project.
So I've typed this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  IplImage* img = 0;

  img=cvLoadImage("C:/.../Pictures/immagine.jpg");     // carica l'immagine

  cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);       // crea la finestra

  cvShowImage("mainWin", img );    //  mostra l'immagine

  cvWaitKey(0);    // wait for a key

  cvReleaseImage(&img );    //rilascia l'immagine

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I have these errors returned:

```
Unresolved inclusion: <cv.h>
Unresolved inclusion: <highgui.h>
```

But in my eclipse workspace project I have these libraries under /usr/include...

What may be wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Just try giving the headers in quotes - `#include "cv.h"`. Standard library headers are enclosed in angle brackets `<>`.

Comment: Solved with include "opencv/cv.h".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute:

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv
```

On my system it returns:

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include
```

Those are the directories you'll have to add on Eclipse to compile your application.

**Or**, you could try replacing your includes for:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
```